# How to check if the bot is in a voice channel?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

When the bot is in a voice channel and I do the leave command, the bot will leave and reply with `leave.result`. But when I'm still in the voice channel and do the command, the bot will reply with the same answer, I want the bot to answer with `leave.errorNotChannel` here is the code

```
execute(message) {     
    const { channel } = message.member.voice;

    const serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
    if (!channel) return message.reply(i18n.__("leave.errorNotChannel")).catch(console.error);
    if (serverQueue && channel !== message.guild.me.voice.channel)
      return message
        .reply(i18n.__mf("leave.errorNotInSameChannel", { user: message.client.user }))
        .catch(console.error);
    
    channel.leave();
    message
    .channel
    .send(i18n.__("leave.result"))
    .catch(console.error);

     }
```

And I don't know how to make the bot knows if it's in a voice channel or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this using an `if` statement:

```js
if (message.guild.me.voice.channel) {
    message.channel.send('I am in a voice channel')
} else {
    message.channel.send('I\'m not in a voice channel')
}
```

What I've done here find the voice channel the bot is connected in (in the guild) the voice channel is defined as `message.guild.me.voice.channel` now if the channel exists you can send an output something like I did or if it isn't connected it'll just send an error

You can customize this further!